# How to connect with Google Sheet?

Tags: python

I have username and password to the database our company use heavily. Everyday I have to download CSVs frequently and then export them to google sheets to make report or analysis. Is there any way to connect Metabase to Google Sheet so that the sheets pull CSVs automatically from database?

Comment: How about retrieving the data using API? [Ref](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/blob/master/docs/api-documentation.md) If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 8):

I've implemented a [Google Sheets add-on as a solution for this and open-sourced it](https://github.com/bplmp/metabase-google-sheets-add-on).

I've used this code as a Google Sheets add-on at a large organization and it has worked well so far, with hundreds of users a week, running tens of thousands of queries.

This is what it looks like in action:

[image: gif of add-on in action]

If you don't want the hassle of setting it up as a Google Sheets add-on, you can take the script and adapt it as a simple Apps Script.

Answer (score 2):

You could try and write a script using Google Apps Script for your issue. An idea would be to use the UrlFetchApp.fetch() method which allows scripts to communicate with other applications or access other resources on the web by making a request to fetch a URL, in your case the Metabase URL.

This following code snippet might give you a glimpse on what to do next:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];

  var data = {
    // the data that you will be using
  };

  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': data
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://metabase.example.com/api/card/1/query/json', options);

  var responseData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  sheet.appendRow(responseData);
}
```

What it actually does: it uses the Metabase API to fetch the data you want by using a `POST` request (the reason a `POST` request is used is because according to the [API Documentation for Metabase v0.32.2](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/blob/master/docs/api-documentation.md) it runs the query associated with a card, and returns its results as a file in the specified format). Then the response from the request is appended to your sheet by using `.appendRow()`.

Furthermore, you can read more about UrlFetchApp and Apps Script here:

1. [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app);
2. [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script);
3. [Spreadsheet App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app).

Answer (score 0):

You can [add a Google Sheet as an external table in Google Big Query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/connected-sheets), then [connect Metabase to Google BigQuery](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/administration-guide/databases/bigquery.html).